# Laravel date_format field validation backwards?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to determine where the issue is here. I'm taking an input of something like "01-02-2018" to refer to January 02, 2018. Then creating a variable to fix it as a standard 2018-01-02 DATE formate for mySQL and saving it. However, when it saves, it is saving it as 2018-02-01, transposing the month and day, which represents February 01, 2018. Here is what my code looks like:

Validation

```
'prescribe_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"m-d-Y"|max:10',
```

Fix

```
$prescribe_dateFix = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->prescribe_date));
```

Save

```
$prescription->prescribe_date = $prescribe_dateFix;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will interpret your date as `d-m-Y` by default so it will think it is 1st February. From the manual:

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

You need to use [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

```
$request = (object)['prescribe_date' => '01-02-2018'];
$prescribe_dateFix = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $request->prescribe_date)->format('Y-m-d');
echo $prescribe_dateFix;
```

Output:

```
2018-01-02
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In the end, I used your tip from the manual and converted to the American '/' separator since the dash was just a style preference that I apparently share with Europeans. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$prescribe_dateFix = date_format($request->prescribe_date, 'Y-m-d')
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Laravelish" way of achieving this is using the built-in Carbon library for smart PHP date manipulation:

```
// Perform validation and then...
$prescription->prescribe_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $request->prescribe_date);
$prescription->save();
```

Of course, you should also specify that the `prescribe_date` field is a date within the corresponding model class (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators):

In `Prescription` model class:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'prescribe_date'
];
```